# Sync non-AD LDAP instance with Office365 / Azure AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap, microsoft-office-365

We have a non-AD LDAP environment that we wish to sync with our o365 Azure AD directory.

Is this currently possible with DirSync, AAD Sync or similar?

Answer (score 2):

(answering my own question)

It now seems like Microsoft has officially launched (in preview) an Azure AD Domain Services solution. This should theoretically allow third party directories to sync (over LDAP) with Azure Active directory to allow O365 credentials to log in to local applications that use that 3rd party directory.

More info can be found [here](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2015/10/14/azure-ad-domain-services-is-now-in-public-preview-use-azure-ad-as-a-cloud-domain-controller/)

Answer (score 0):

Full FIM (Forefront identity manager) has a connector available, but the purpose built Sync tools are only supported for connection to Active Directory.

You may also want to consider services like Okta may serve tour need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the current tool (azure ad connect) but not with the old dirsync tool.

Comment: hi JimB thanks for your answer. Looking at the link provided in blaughw answer, it seems like it may not actually be in Azure AD Connect yet. Do you have confirmation that this functionality actually exists in this tool?

Comment: I would love to be wrong! :)

Comment: Azure AD Connect is highly customized version of FIM - it doesn't currently support 3rd party connections.  If you look at the connectors that ship with it it's only AD and O365.  "Technically" you can probably create your own connectors - but you will need to bust out VS and code it.  I have not had a chance to re-read the use agreement but that is probably in violation of it (B/C Microsoft would rater sell you FIM).

Comment: Since connecting with FIM is no longer supported I doubt they are trying to sell FIM.  I'm still looking to see if aad connect with ldap is available.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD Connect is the current (rather new) tool for all of this. It does not currently support a plain LDAP source provider, but this is in the roadmap. [Azure AD Connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-get-started-tools-comparison/)

Comment: OK so it is in the pipeline, but not yet implemented?  Do you know of any other alternatives for synchronizing this data without going down the full SAML SSO provider route?

Comment: With PowerShell you can use a CSV of user attributes and create accounts "from scratch" in the cloud.  This will not allow you to get password hash sync, must less identity federation.

Answer (score -2):

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnectsync-connector-genericldap/ < things have changed a touch. You'll want FIM or MIM to leverage this (the MS Identity Management product became significantly more affordable when it for bundled into Azure AD Premium and, by extension, EMS), but there is support for non AD LDAP sources.